# When Javascript math.random method is seeded

Tags: javascript, random, seed

I would like to know when, in a browser environment  Javascripts `math.random` method is seeded.

Is it:

A)  When computer is switched on

B)  When the browser is launched for the first time on a session

C)  Each time the browser is launched

D)  When the page with JS code containing `math.random` is opened for the first time

E)  Each time that the page containing `math.random` is opened

F)  When `math.random()` method is called for the first time

G)  Others

Comment: As it's seeded from the current time, what difference does it make ? You can't use the difference between A, B D or F.

Comment: The fact is JS's Math.random is the only random lib I know not letting you set the seed, which is very unfortunate.

Comment: @dystroy it is long to explain and my english could not be enough accurate to do it, but the answer could be useful for me. Thanks

Comment: You know there is a different seed each time, right ?

Answer (score 1):

From [ECMAScript](http://es5.github.io/#x15.8.2.14) :

> Returns a Number value with positive sign, greater than or equal to 0
>   but less than 1, chosen randomly or pseudo randomly with approximately
>   uniform distribution over that range, **using an
>   implementation-dependent algorithm or strategy**.

So, it depends on the browser.

As **it doesn't make any practical difference** (as long as it isn't seeded while your pages run) because the seed is itself kindof random (usually based on the timestamp of seeding time), browser documentations are sparse but [here's what Internet Explorer's one says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/41336409%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) :

> The random number generator is seeded automatically when JavaScript is
>   first loaded.

As most other strategies would induce potential errors, I think you can assume there won't be any new seeding between the first call to `Math.random` and the browser closing.

Comment: Good information. So, do you think that when you close de browser and open it again JS is loaded again and math.random seeded again?   Do you have a link for Chrome and Firefox math.random specifications?   Thanks for your help.

Comment: The seed is "random" itself and the pseudo-generator isn't open, so how can it possibly change anything to you ? Regarding Firefox, they say it's timestamp based but don't give details and they shouldn't give details.